# key is AWSPinpoint_MYKEY with options undefined

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I am getting the following message:

Get item: key is AWSPinpoint_"My_aws_mobile_analytics_app_id" with options undefined

All my info on my aws-export.js are matching my project.

Once I click on the message, the sources from AsyncStorageCache.js:526 says:

```
/**
 * Get item from cache. It will return null if item doesn’t exist or it has been expired.
 * If you specified callback function in the options,
 * then the function will be executed if no such item in the cache
 * and finally put the return value into cache.
 * Please make sure the callback function will return the value you want to put into the cache.
 * The cache will abort output a warning:
 * If the key is invalid
 * If error happened with AsyncStorage
 *
 * @param {String} key - the key of the item
 * @param {Object} [options] - the options of callback function
 * @return {Promise} - return a promise resolves to be the value of the item
 */
```

I am not sure why I'm getting this error if the key is defined on my my aws-export.js

Thanks for your help